# reverse "inequality sign" presenting order in decision tree built in rpart or partykit

Tags: decision-tree, rpart, party, inequality

I have built a multi-layer decision tree using `rpart` and I am trying to replicate the tree structure using `partykit` package, more specifically, the `partysplit`-`partynode`combo.

I am currently having an issue with the order difference between `rpart` and `partysplit`.

The decision tree coming from `rpart` always take "greater than" sign (>) first then "less than" sign (<) underneath while `partykit` is the opposite. 
e.g., the `rpart` output

```
 [6] value.a >= 33: FALSE. (n = 63, err = 33.3%)
 [7] value.a< 33: FALSE. (n = 74, err = 8.1%)
```

vs. the `partykit` output

```
 [6] value.a < 33: FALSE. (n = 74, err = 8.1%)
 [7] value.a >= 33: FALSE. (n = 63, err = 33.3%)
```

As a result, I am having trouble reading the decision tree in correct order and using `partykit` to recreate the tree from `rpart`.

Is there a way I can create a tree from `rpart` such as the tree take "less than" sign first,  or is there an option on `partysplit` such that you make the split take the "greater than" sign first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `partysplit()` constructor function provides the arguments `index` and `right` which can be used to create all combinations. The `index` controls whether the left part of the interval is presented first or second. The `right` argument controls where the equal sign goes. For a simple dummy data set:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
```

we can create all for combinations:

```
sp1 <- partysplit(1L, 5.5, index = 1:2, right = TRUE)
sp2 <- partysplit(1L, 5.5, index = 2:1, right = TRUE)
sp3 <- partysplit(1L, 5.5, index = 1:2, right = FALSE)
sp4 <- partysplit(1L, 5.5, index = 2:1, right = FALSE)
```

Then the corresponding character labels can be computed as:

```
character_split(sp1, d)$levels
## [1] "<= 5.5" "> 5.5" 
character_split(sp2, d)$levels
## [1] "> 5.5"  "<= 5.5"
character_split(sp3, d)$levels
## [1] "< 5.5"  ">= 5.5"
character_split(sp4, d)$levels
## [1] ">= 5.5" "< 5.5"
```

The `as.party()` method for `rpart` objects tries to preserve this. For example:

```
library("partykit")
library("rpart")
iris2 <- iris[1:100,]
rp <- rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris2)
rp
## n= 100 
## 
## node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
##       * denotes terminal node
## 
## 1) root 100 50 setosa (0.5000000 0.5000000)  
##   2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50  0 setosa (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
##   3) Petal.Length>=2.45 50  0 versicolor (0.0000000 1.0000000) *
as.party(rp)
## Model formula:
## Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] Petal.Length < 2.45: setosa (n = 50, err = 0.0%)
## |   [3] Petal.Length >= 2.45: versicolor (n = 50, err = 0.0%)
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    1
## Number of terminal nodes: 2
```

Comment: As always, thank you so much for the help! You have been instrumental to my study on decision tree using R and I really appreciate your input!

Comment: No problem, glad if it's useful!